# R ggplot, Add a new data to boxplot

Tags: r

I have 74 distributions of population data of some test scores from geographical locations represented by boxplot, horizontally, 74 boxplot rows. I have them sorted by the mean, not by the median.  So far I have no problems.
2. How to add an additional data to each of the boxplot,for example the scores that students with certain characteristics have, not having a class book or missing class frequently. I have rephrased the question. I want to avoid writing my attempts and the errors obtained for fear of being misguided. I have been thinking about this issue for days and I don't know if using ggplot is really possible. Sorry for my English.

```
  `ggplot(datos_completo, aes(x=PV1MATH,y=reorder(CNT,PV1MATH,FUN = mean)))+ 
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", shape=5, colour="red",size=4)`
```

[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spdl9.jpg)

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a variable to the aesthetic, but your data is not tidy. If that's the case, you might want to use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to your data.